# .insertAfter reordering string in variable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working with an external system that writes antiquated code, but have access to css and javascript. I am working with a table that writes each item on an individual row, in some cases up to 30 rows. I need to break up the tr's into 6 rows of 5 items.

The plan was to change each tr's style to display:table-cell to make them list horizontally. Then add a class to every 5th row. Then insert ending and beginnning tbody and table tags after every 5th tr with the added class, to create individual tables for every 5 tr's. Thus forcing each 5 tr's to exist in its own table and create rows of 5.

Everything works except for .insertAfter. I need `</tbody></table><table class='tableBreaker'><tbody>` to be inserted after every 5th tr, but it reverses my code and writes `<table class="tableBreaker"><tbody></tbody></table>`.

I can't find any info on jquery rewriting strings in .insertAfter.

Table HTML:

```
<table id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList" class="tnew-selectseating-form-zone-radio">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="151" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$0\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_0">&nbsp;10:15</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="152" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$1\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_1">&nbsp;10:30</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="153" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$2\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_2">&nbsp;10:45</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="154" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$3\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_3">&nbsp;11:00</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_4" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="155" checked="checked"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_4">&nbsp;11:15</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_5" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="156" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$5\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_5">&nbsp;11:30</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_6" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="157" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$6\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_6">&nbsp;11:45</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_7" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="158" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$7\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_7">&nbsp;12:00</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_8" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="159" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$8\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_8">&nbsp;12:15</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_9" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList" value="160" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$mainContent$rbl_zoneList$9\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="mainContent_rbl_zoneList_9">&nbsp;12:30</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table#mainContent_rbl_zoneList tr {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#mainContent_rbl_zoneList.tnew-selectseating-form-zone-radio tr").each( function (index) {
  index += 1;
  if(index % 5 == 0) {
    $(this).addClass("breakRow");
  }
});

var tableBreaker = "</tbody></table><table class='tableBreaker'><tbody>";
$(tableBreaker).insertAfter('tr.breakRow');
```

Comment: Can't treat the dom like a text editor. When inserting elements they are complete elements, your html becomes a dom node object...you can't insert a new close and open tag like you can do with copy/paste in text editor....it just doesn't work that way

Comment: What actual DOM your tableBreaker represent?

Comment: You can create new table followed first. and migrate all rows after marked from first to second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should move the `rowCount` rows to new table(s) moving the old table classes to the new one(s).

```
function movem(rowCount) {
  var oldTable = $('#mainContent_rbl_zoneList'),
    holder = oldTable.parent().eq(0),
    rows = oldTable.find('tr');
  var classes = oldTable.prop("classList");
  var temptable = $('<table>');
  $.each(classes, function(index, value) {
    temptable.addClass(value);
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i = i + rowCount) {
    var newTable = temptable.clone(),
      tbody = $('<tbody>');
    rows.slice(i, i + 5).appendTo(tbody);
    newTable.append(tbody).appendTo(holder);
  }
  oldTable.remove();
}
movem(5);
```

This MIGHT generate issues if you have event handlers bound to the old table, you would need to account for that.

Note that I applied the NEW tables to the end of the OLD tables parent container whatever that was.

To fix the CSS, you might also do:

```
temptable.addClass("rowcontainer");
```

and

```
.rowcontainer tr {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Sample to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/n3nqespn/

Comment: You might also consider passing a reference to the OLD table instead of hard coding the id.

Comment: This works great, and solves a couple of problems I hadn't encountered earlier. The temptable.addClass("rowcontainer"); adds the class to the table element, but I can figure that out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you are ultimately attempting to do with your `insertAfter` is create new tables you will actually need to do just that and move the rows to the new tables

Something like:

```
var $container = $('#mainContent_rbl_zoneList'),
    $rows = $('#mainContent_rbl_zoneList tr');

for(var i=0; i < $rows.length; i = i+5 ){
   var $newTable = $('<table>'), $tbody = $('<tbody>');
   $rows.slice(i, i+5).appendto($tbody);
   $newTable.append($tbody).appendTo($container);      

}
```

this is just roughed out and doesn't take the row classes into account